# For Each Loop giving error (Next without For)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, foreach

```
Heading_Value = "L"

For Each cell In Range(Heading_Start, Heading_End)
    
    cell.Value = Heading_Value
    
    If Heading_Value = "L" Then
        Heading_Value = "R"
        If Heading_Value = "R" Then
            Heading_Value = "Total"
        Else
            Heading_Value = "L"
        End If
Next cell
```

the 2 variables in the range correspond to cell addresses for example "Heading Start" = Range "A5"

not sure why this is saying next without for im guessing I did something wrong with the Nested If Statements

basically its supposed to go through a range (Lets say Row 1 Columns A:F

should look like

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | R | Total | T | R | Total |

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `End If` closing outer `If Heading_Value = "L" Then`

```
        Else
            Heading_Value = "L"
        End If
    End If  <-- here
Next cell
```

Comment: much appreciated, I found a workaround but glad to know where I went wrong the first time

Answer (score 1):

### From *Fill a Row* to *Fill a Range*

**Basic Issues**

- Always use `Option Explicit`. It will force you to declare almost all variables and in return detect most of the errors at compile time.
- Referencing the worksheet is crucial to be able to qualify all ranges e.g.

  ```
  Set hrg = ws.Range(hStartCell, hEndCell) ' focus on 'ws.'
  ```

  so they don't get referenced from the wrong worksheet.
- If the code will not run on multiple worksheets, specify the worksheet explicitly with e.g.

  ```
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' (tab) name
  ```

  or even better with

  ```
  Set ws = Sheet1 ' code name
  ```
- Otherwise, make sure that an active sheet exists and that it's not a chart:

  ```
  If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
  If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
  ```

**Main**

- This is the beginning of the code where some of the above is already implemented.
- Replace `' One of the ideas here!` with the codes of any of the below 'ideas' or replace `' Main code here!` in the ideas with this code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    ' Just an example.
    Dim hStartCell As Range: Set hStartCell = ws.Range("A1")
    Dim hEndCell As Range: Set hEndCell = ws.Range("K1")
    ' Reference the range: qualify with worksheet ('ws.')
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = ws.Range(hStartCell, hEndCell)

    ' One of the ideas here!

End Sub
```

**Basic**

- You need to keep in mind to set `hIndex = 1` before the loop.
- You need to keep in mind to add `hIndex = 0` to the last case.
- Adding more cases is not simple enough.

```vb
Sub Idea1()

    ' Main code here!

    Dim hIndex As Long: hIndex = 1

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In hrg.Cells
        Select Case hIndex
            Case 1: cell.Value = "L"
            Case 2: cell.Value = "R"
            Case 3: cell.Value = "Total": hIndex = 0
        End Select
        hIndex = hIndex + 1
    Next cell

End Sub
```

**Improved**

- Introducing the *Mod* operator took care of some of the previous issues, yet adding more cases still remains not simple enough.

```vb
Sub Idea2()

    ' Main code here!

    Dim cell As Range, hIndex As Long

    For Each cell In hrg.Cells
        hIndex = hIndex Mod 3
        Select Case hIndex
            Case 0: cell.Value = "L"
            Case 1: cell.Value = "R"
            Case 2: cell.Value = "Total"
        End Select
        hIndex = hIndex + 1
    Next cell

End Sub
```

**Good**

- Adding more cases is done by simply adding items to the array.
- Note how this works for any single-row or single-column range.

```vb
Sub Idea3()

    ' 'VBA.' ensures a zero-based array.
    Dim Headers(): Headers = VBA.Array("L", "R", "Total")

    ' Main code here!

    Dim hCount As Long: hCount = UBound(Headers) + 1

    Dim cell As Range, hIndex As Long

    For Each cell In hrg.Cells
        cell.Value = Headers(hIndex Mod hCount)
        hIndex = hIndex + 1
    Next cell

End Sub
```

**Better (still slow)**

- By placing the code in a separate procedure, the relevant code is reduced to a single line making your main procedure more readable.

```vb
Sub Idea4()

    Dim Headers(): Headers = Array("L", "R", "Total")

    ' Main code here!

    WriteRepeatingHeaders hrg, Headers

End Sub

Sub WriteRepeatingHeadersRange( _
        ByVal HeaderRange As Range, _
        Headers() As Variant)

    ' *** These 'complications' ensure that a 1D array of any lower limit (base)
    ' is accepted.
    Dim hLB As Long: hLB = LBound(Headers) '***
    Dim hCount As Long: hCount = UBound(Headers) - hLB + 1 '***

    Dim cell As Range, hIndex As Long

    For Each cell In HeaderRange.Cells
        cell.Value = Headers(hIndex Mod hCount + hLB) '***
        hIndex = hIndex + 1
    Next cell

End Sub
```

**Great (Final)**

- By introducing an array to write the results to it and finally write them to the range in one go, the code becomes more efficient (faster).
- With a few additional changes, we have almost accidentally created a multi-purpose procedure that can be used on any range. Try it first with a single row and a single column. Then try it with multiple rows and columns to see how it works.
- By introducing the 3rd argument (`False` by default), you can now get different results for the same multi-row and multi-column range.

```vb
Sub Final()

    Dim Headers(): Headers = Array("L", "R", "Total")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    ' Just an example.
    Dim hStartCell As Range: Set hStartCell = ws.Range("A1")
    Dim hEndCell As Range: Set hEndCell = ws.Range("K1")
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = ws.Range(hStartCell, hEndCell)

    WriteRepeatingValues hrg, Headers

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Repeatedly writes the values from a 1D array to a range.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub WriteRepeatingValues( _
        ByVal DestinationRange As Range, _
        Values() As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal ByColumns As Boolean = False)
        
    Dim vLB As Long: vLB = LBound(Values)
    Dim vCount As Long: vCount = UBound(Values) - vLB + 1
    
    With DestinationRange
        
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Rows.Count
        Dim cCount As Long: cCount = .Columns.Count
        Dim Data(): ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
        
        Dim r As Long, c As Long, vIndex As Long
        
        If ByColumns Then
            For c = 1 To cCount
                For r = 1 To rCount
                    Data(r, c) = Values(vIndex Mod vCount + vLB)
                    vIndex = vIndex + 1
                Next r
            Next c
        Else ' by rows
            For r = 1 To rCount
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    Data(r, c) = Values(vIndex Mod vCount + vLB)
                    vIndex = vIndex + 1
                Next c
            Next r
       End If
    
        .Value = Data
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround

```
Heading_Value = 1

For Each cell In Range(Heading_Start, Heading_End)
    
    cell.Value = "H" & Heading_Value
    
    If Heading_Value = 3 Then
        Heading_Value = 0
    End If
    
    Heading_Value = Heading_Value + 1
    
Next cell

With Range(Heading_Start, Heading_End)
    .Replace what:="H1", Replacement:="L"
    .Replace what:="H2", Replacement:="R"
    .Replace what:="H3", Replacement:="Total"
End With
```